# вывести ng-minlength

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Добрый день, есть код:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="16" ng-model="data.firstname" required>
<div ng-show="showError">{{getError(regForm.firstname)}}</div>

$scope.getError = (error) => {
    if (angular.isDefined(error)) {

        $scope.showError = true

        if (error.$error.minlength) {
            return "Минимальная длина - ??? символа!";
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно вывести в место где "Минимальная длина - ??? символа" ту цифру которая написана в атрибуте ng-minlength?

Comment: в данном случае никак. Задавай данные значения из кода, тогда они в коде будут сразу доступны

Comment: Получалось вывести вот так: " Минимальная длина -  firstname.getAttribute('ng-minlength') символов". В этом случае firstname - это id инпута, а вот как подсовывать ему эти значения если нужно через этот метод прогнать скажем 5 полей?

Comment: Были мысли передавать его вторым аттрибутом в getError, а вот что написать в getError(regForm.firstname, ???), чтобы он передавал его как id не знаю.

Comment: это плохой _firstname.getAttribute('ng-minlength')_ - это плохой подход, смешить ангуляр и прямую работу с DOM